# How to get site page collection via graph sdk method?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Tried this:
graphServiceClient
.sites(siteId)
.pages(pageId)
.buildRequest()
.get() but seems earlier pages method was supported and now it's not appearing.
Is there any way to get site page collection?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reaching out ,I understood that you are trying to get list of sites, looks like you are using async await ,please convert your get() function to GetAync() and add await.

Could you please try by using the below sample code

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider    );

```
   var items = await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Lists["{list-id}"].Items    .Request()
.GetAsync();
```

ref docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request

Hope this helps , please let us know if you have any query
thanks

Comment: Please remember to "Accept Answer" if answer helped you.